# Read Data From Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

This question is only to get some idea how it would be better to implement some functionality.

I need to read data from Excel into a set, which I need later to export, ex: into sql database, into a new Excel document, etc.
But the problem is that the Excel document is not structured. So I cannot read a whole range, but instead I need to look into specific cells for specific values. The "schema" of Excel changes, ex: new rows are added, new columns are added, etc.

What do you think it would be the best way to achieve this. What I can think is to create a XML schema, and then create a class from that schema which will read cells or ranges in Excel. All ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up your connection string properly, you can access data in Excel as if you're working with a database. The sheets become tables.

I've used this method to set up a SLQBulkCopy to a database with some large Excel files a user needs to upload through a web interface, where the requirement was for users to load large amounts of data from an Excel file through a web based interface.

[Setting up an Excel connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

You may need to tweak this approach since your Excel file isn't structured.